# How do I plot a function with multiple different values for constants?

Tags: python

I am trying to plot this function: y(x) = (e^-ax)cos(x)

For x value spanning the interval (0,4pi) and 'a' ranging from 0 to 1 in steps of 0.25.  I have managed to successfully plot this for a=0.

However, I am wondering if I can write some code that will allow me to plot it for the range of 'a' values, instead of having to rewrite the code for each different 'a' value.

Here is the code I have: (Note y = cos(x) as this is for a = 0)

```
from numpy import *

import pylab as p


# function to plot ( a = 0 )
x = linspace(0, 4*pi, 100)
y = cos(x)


#plot the function
p.plot(x,y,'o')

# axis annotation
p.xlabel('x-variable')
p.ylabel('y=(e**-ax)cosx')

# graph title
p.title('Plot of function')

#set axis range
p.axis([-0.5, 4*pi, -1.3, 1.3])
# turn grid on
p.grid(True)
p.show()
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

assuming that you want everything on the same plot...

```
from numpy import linspace, pi, cos, exp

import pylab as p

for a in p.frange(xini=0, xfin=1, delta=0.25):
    x = linspace(0, 4*pi, 100) 
    y = exp(-a*x)*cos(x)
    p.plot(x,y,'o')

# axis annotation
p.xlabel('x-variable')
p.ylabel('y=(e**-ax)cosx')

# graph title
p.title('Plot of function')

#set axis range
p.axis([-0.5, 4*pi, -1.3, 1.3])
# turn grid on
p.grid(True)
p.show()
```